# Removing unnecessary drop-shadow from MapBox GL logo

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

The current MapBox attribution logo was obviously made so it would display on both light and dark backgrounds:

[image]

However, this universal display comes at the cost of looking unprofessional from a graphic design perspective.

Is there a way to replace it with a shadowless version, or perhaps replace it altogether in favor of going back to a regular text one?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: It looks bad, Steve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This particular [Mapbox wordmark](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/#mapbox-wordmark) is required for attribution purposes, as detailed [in our attribution guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/). It is not possible to change the wordmark to remove the drop shadow or replace it with a regular text version. Note that the proper [text attribution](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/#text-attribution) is also a requirement. You can [contact our sales team](https://www.mapbox.com/contact/sales/) if you are interested in removing the wordmark entirely, but the text attribution will still be necessary in this case.